# Find all the Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to know how to find all the homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{7}]$ and $\mathbb{C}$ ?
Thank you.

Comment: Did your textbook not give you any examples? Did your teacher just toss you to the deep end??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a roadmap.
If $f: \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{7}] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a ring homomorphism, then:

- $f(q)=q$ for every $q \in \mathbb{Q}$
- $f(\sqrt{-3})$ is a root of $x^2+3$
- $f(\sqrt{7})$ is a root of $x^2-7$
- $f$ is determined by the images of $\sqrt{-3}$ and $\sqrt{7}$

Indeed, let $\alpha = \sqrt{-3} = 3i$ and $\beta = \sqrt{7}$. Then

$$\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{7}] = \{ a + b \alpha + c \beta + d \alpha\beta : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q} \}$$ and so
$$
f(a + b \alpha + c \beta + d \alpha\beta)
=a + b f(\alpha) + c f(\beta) + d f(\alpha)f(\beta)
$$
because $f$ is  a ring homomorphism that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$.
So the question reduces to

> How many possible images exist for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Field homomorphism

Comment: @Ahmedtoub, same thing.

Comment: what did you use to prove that f(q)=q ?

Comment: @Ahmedtoub, $f(n)=f(1+\cdots+1)=f(1)+\cdots+f(1)=1+\cdots+1=n$.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: sorry, but i want to know  if we can prove too that a map who verifies the 3 first conditions are a Field homomorphism ?

Comment: sorry but there's a little problem, because we didn't show if $f$ verifies the 3 first conditions then it's a homomorphism !!

Comment: @Ahmedtoub, by hypothesis, $f$ is a homomorphism, that is, is additive and multiplicative.

Comment: yes i know but if we assume that $f$ is already a homomorphism so we won't add anything new, i don't know how to explain it

Comment: i want to prove that if f verifies the 3 conditions so it's a homomorphism

Comment: @Ahmedtoub, that is not the point of the question.